# SQL query to get subset of field based on other field (COUNT?)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I will illustrate the problem in the simplest terms. Imagine we are the manager of a bookstore and every day we can see the sales that took place at our brick-and-mortar establishment. They look as in the table below.

[image]

This basic data shows us, for example, that a certain customer whose receipt ID was RD226 bought 1 book worth 25$ and 4 non-book items (e.g. paper, pencils, maybe a calendar etc) worth 100$. My question is: how can I find the receipt ID associated with just one type of product and, as a corollary, with both product type, and some aggregates (in this case, the sum of quantity sold and the sum of value)?

I would image a query like:

```
SELECT [RECEIPT ID], SUM([QUANTITY]) AS QNT, SUM([VALUE]) AS SALESV 
FROM [TABLEA]
WHERE PRODUCT = 'BOOK'
GROUP BY [RECEIPT ID];
```

Now, obviously, if I run this query I also get the "book part" of those receipts that have both books and non-books, and this is not correct. The query I need would return only receipts associated with books, so R225, R228 and R230, and their respective quantities and values. I believe this implies COUNT, but in MS ACCESS COUNT(DISTINCT) is not possible. Any idea how to get a simple and clean result as above with a query?

Answer (score 0):

After plenty of trials and errors, I came up with a solution. I'm not sure if this is the most elegant one, but it does the job. Say I want only the receipts that contain books. In that case, I make sure the query picks only those receipts whose count of 'Book' is equal to the total number of receipt positions.

```
SELECT [RECEIPT ID], SUM([QUANTITY]) AS Q, SUM([VALUE]) AS V
FROM [TABLE A] 
GROUP BY [RECEIPT ID]
HAVING SUM(IIF([PRODUCT]='Book',1,0))=COUNT([RECEIPT ID]);
```

Alternatively, we could also select the receipts whose count of 'Non-Book' is zero....

```
SELECT [RECEIPT ID], SUM([QUANTITY]) AS Q, SUM([VALUE]) AS V
FROM [TABLE A] 
GROUP BY [RECEIPT ID]
HAVING SUM(IIF([PRODUCT]='Non-Book',1,0))=0;
```